# Game object и текст

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте. Я создал объект и добавил на него спрайт и текстмэш. Далее создал префаб данного объекта. В коде создаю 17 таких объектов.

```
for (int i = 0; i < position.Length; i++) {

    blocks [i] = Instantiate (apple, position [i], Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

    TextMesh tm = blocks [i].GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
    print (tm.text);                
}
```

Мне нужно вывести текст каждого объекта (через принт), но выводит ошибку, что нет такого объекта с текстмэш.

Структура префаба:

```
Сам объект:
--Спрайт,
--Тексмэш
```

Заранее спасибо.

Текст ошибки:

> There is no 'TextMesh' attached to the "AppleNumber(Clone)" game
>   object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably need to add
>   a TextMesh to the game object "AppleNumber(Clone)". Or your script
>   needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос точный текст ошибки.

Comment: Может вы добавили его на объект, который был на сцене, и не применили `apply` ? можно скрин префаба в инспекторе?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил. А по поводу "применить", то возможно, и не нажал. Создать префаб заново?

Comment: @ДмитрийКоверко ну как видим из фото никакого textmesh на префабе нет. собственно его надо добавить и нажать apply чтоб он применился потом...... хотя, смотрю, тоже самое написали в ответе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, В префабе он есть,"Number", но я не так его добавил. Все исправил и норм работает. Вопрос я уже закрыл))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте его вручную в инспекторе справа